# Llamar a una funcion del AppDelegate.swift desde un archivo .m. Objective-c mezclado con swift

Tags: swift2, swift, objective-c, swift3

Estoy haciendo una app en `swift`, pero he tenido que usar una libreria que solo está en `objective-c`, por lo que he tenido que crear un archivo `.h` y otro archivo `.m`

El problema es que desde el archivo `.m` tengo que llamar a una función del `AppDelegate` que esta en `swift` pero nose como llamarla, porque me dice que `AppDelegate` no está declarado.

Cómo puedo hacerlo??

Comment: Sin código no podemos ayudarte. Y por otro lado, deberías plantearte si es necesario que llames directamente a la función o hay una alternativa mejor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay un header que se genera automaticamente cuando compilas.

```
#import "ModuleName-Swift.h"
```

ModuleName depende del nombre de tu proyecto. Si tu proyecto se llama TestProyect, pues será TestProyect-Swift.h

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente no he realizado la prueba, pero de acuerdo a la documentación es posible que coexistan ambos códigos en el mismo proyecto.

Te dejo la documentación de Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Saludos.